# Git command - Repository heads not listed while using -h switch with "HEAD" option

Tags: git, jenkins, github, version-control, ls-remote

There is a git repository in my LAN. I try to query Git to list all the HEAD references in the following way:

**Method 1**

*Command*

```
git ls-remote -h username@{ip-address}:/path/to/repo
```

*Output*

```
f0467f266dee55cd32f2ca6fa819814f367db899    HEAD
```

**Method 2**

*Command*

```
git ls-remote username@{ip-address}:/path/to/repo HEAD
```

*Output*

```
f0467f266dee55cd32f2ca6fa819814f367db899    HEAD
```

**Method 3**

*Command*

```
git ls-remote -h username@{ip-address}:/path/to/repo HEAD
```

When using the above command, the head reference which was listed in the above two methods is not listed.

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is because `HEAD` is a special kind of refs, it's not a head of a branch, it doesn't reside in `refs/heads/` namespace. So when you ask git to list refs with both `-h` and `HEAD` git sees a contradiction and doesn't list any refs.